# nServiceBus QA testing tool

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

Does anyone know of a tool or have a good solution for QA to test individual nServiceBus endpoints in isolation?   We have multiple publishers and subscribers in our system and we'd like to test them in isolation.  For example, to test our publishers we'd like to be able to have a tool that our QA can use to easily subscribe/unsubscribe to different publishers so they can get messages delivered to their "QA queue" for validation of the messages.   To test subscribers, we'd like them to be able to publish messages directly to the subscribers input queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wired up wcf endpoints for pub entry.  Created a subscriber for qa that saves message in RavenDB.  Since having multiple handlers for same type in pub does not work, wcf endpoint message is new class with the main message as the base class.  Then QA can use soapui or other testing client.

Answer (score 1):

There's an integration testing framework called [BizUnit](http://bizunit.codeplex.com/) which allows you to declaratively define integration tests. It comes with some pre-defined steps for enqueuing/listening to MSMQ.

You would probably have to write your own custom step for enqueuing because of the message header information required by NServiceBus.

While this is geared towards BizTalk testing, it has no dependency whatsoever on BizTalk being installed or available.

This is the only thing that springs to mind. It's a great framework for the testing of any distributed system.

Answer (score 1):

You could put together an assembly that simply is configured correctly as a Subscriber with a pre-defined endpoint name.  The only configuration would be to pass along the endpoint(message mapping) to modify the config file.  I'd imagine your could wrap this up in a script and just have QA run the script with a command line parameter.  PowerShell comes to mind since its so eazy to manipulate XML.  This could look like "Subscribe-To-EndPoint Messages.dll endpoint_name"

Answer (score 1):

Turn auditing on for your endpoints(ForwardReceivedMessagesTo) and write some code that verifies that the expected messages end up in the audit queue.

Comment: As far as I can tell the auditing really doesn't apply for testing a publisher in isolation.   In my qa environment, I've got a publisher ready to be tested without any real subscribers yet.   Without having an actual subscriber it appears the ForwardReceivedMessagesTo doesn't apply.

Comment: Just send a subsciption message to your publisher to cause it to crete a "QA" subscription and verify that the expected message ends up in the fake subscriber queue when you trigger the publisher